# Eclipse from ADT bundle crashes in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu-14.04

Whenever there is an auto complete window, eclipse crashes. I searched the internet and found out that putting " -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla " this line at the end of eclipse.ini file will solve the problem. It solved my problem initially but now the same problem is happening. Please help me out.

Comment: Android Studio is the official IDE of Android. Make the switch.

Comment: 1. What version of Eclipse is that using?


2. Have you tried forcing it to use the webkit browser instead?
`-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=webkit`


3. Go through the related topics in the SWT FAQ and see which case applies:

[https://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#whatisbrowser](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#whatisbrowser)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your version of Eclipse is up to date, and try not to build it from source. The [Ubuntu Software Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/eclipse-platform/) has the latest version.

Uninstall the version of Eclipse (make sure to do a complete removal - use Synaptic or type `sudo apt-get purge eclipse-platform` in a terminal), then install through the software Center.

Comment: This answer is incomplete, because not enough information is supplied in the question.